# graph traversal in C

Tags: c, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have to implement a backtracing algorithm in C which will emulate a hardware in purely software, and trace a single path from output of a system to the input pin, registering all the gates, their outputs and inputs(taken) on the path in a reverse order. I figured out that it can be done in graph traversal algorithm but not able to implement in C. Any useful suggestions shall be helpful indeed!

Comment: Please be more specific, can you update the question and give a short input and output example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a few maze solving algorithms, both breadth and depth first search.
I'd say you should first build a graph and make sure its perfectly built and without any incoherence, and something i found to be very useful was to find a way to print my graph to check for errors :).
Other than that, good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of path tracing, it can follow both breadth first search or else Depth first search. I have tried both of them and it works.